# Running application on EC2 - Trigger it with RESTful API - Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a standalone adobe after effects script. 
The script input: Takes a video file and some data
The script output: Multiple video files

I want to deploy my script on EC2 instance and achieve the following goals:

1) Call the standalone script to run with a given input (video file & some data)

2) Split the data into batches so that we can run the script in parallel to produce output video files.

3) Place the output video files into S3. Access them with CDN.

I have questions about how to achieve step 1 & 2.

For step 1, Do I need to setup an API to call the script on EC2 ? If yes, how should I do it ? Any documentation pointers will be really helpful.

For Step 1, another option could be to place the input into S3 and find a solution to trigger the script on EC2 when new files are uploaded on S3. IS there any such solution ?

For Step 2, Are there any Map Reduce solutions on AWS which can help with splitting the job into parallel tasks ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest your option 2 for step 1.
You can store your "input" data files into an S3 bucket. Have some CloudWatch events/rules configured for any activity on this specific bucket such as upload of a new file.
This CloudWatch event, when executed, should call a target, which will execute a script to perform the operation to split the data and upload the new video files on S3.

Something like this :

[image]

One option is to write a Lambda function. However, before going for that, consider its limitations with respect to its execution time, memory allocation, cold starts etc.

Another option is to trigger ECS cluster. You'll have to containerize your script/application for the same.

Another option is to trigger SSM Run Command, which will run a script on an EC2 instance you specify.